# Spring Boot can't connect to MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, database-connection

this is my first exercise with Spring Boot and this is my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/notedb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*******
```

These are my classes:

1. DemoMySqlApplication.java

   package com.example.demomysql;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

   @SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

   @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.joydeep.springboot"})
   public class DemoMysqlApplication {

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoMysqlApplication.class, args);


    }
   ```
2. NoteRepository.java (interface):

```
package com.example.demomysql;
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
     
    public interface NoteRepository extends CrudRepository <Note, Integer>{
    
    }
```

3. NoteController.java

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    
    
       @RestController
        @RequestMapping(value="/note")
        public class NoteController {
            
            
            @Autowired
            private NoteRepository noteRepository;
            
            @GetMapping(value="/all")
            public String getAllNotes(Model model) {
                model.addAttribute("notes", noteRepository.findAll());
                return "list";
            }
            
            @GetMapping(value="/debug")
            public @ResponseBody Iterable<Note> getNotes(){
                return noteRepository.findAll();
            }
            
        }
```

4. Note.java (Entity class)

```
package com.example.demomysql;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Entity
public class Note {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Boolean done;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Boolean getDone() {
        return done;
    }
    public void setDone(Boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }
    

}
```

From the console, I don't see errors. Tomcat starts normally. These are the last two information:

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''

Started DemoMysqlApplication in 0.731 seconds (JVM running for 480.726)
```

But on my MySQL database (I created a DB named "notedb" and a table named "note", before to launch this application). I have one row with the data in note. But when I try to connect to:
`http://localhost:8080/note/debug`
I see:

[image]

I think I have a problem with Controller class.
Please, can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: use _@SpringBootApplication_ without exclusions and _@ComponentScan_ and use _@Controller_ and not _@Restcontroller_ this should solve the 404

Comment: leave out _spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_ , don't need it, spring will detect from the connection-url, no need to provide a version either (pom). And make sure mysql is running... _remark if you want to provide the driverClassName, make sure you use the correct one: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_

Comment: I did your changes: I deleted  the exclution and the @ComponentScan from my class Note Controller.  Then, I corrected spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Now I have this problem on my console: Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/notedb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notedb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

---

- Remove

  - `exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}`
  - `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.joydeep.springboot"})`
- Keep `@RestController` remove `@ResponseBody`
- For `@Controller` keep `@ResponseBody` or `ResponseEntity<T>`
- Change return type `Iterable<Note>` to `List<Note>`

---

*Application*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoMysqlApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoMysqlApplication.class, args);
    }
```

---

*Rest Controller*

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/note")
    public class NoteController {

        @Autowired
        private NoteRepository noteRepository;

        @GetMapping(value="/debug")
        public List<Note> getNotes(){
            return noteRepository.findAll();
        }

    }
```

---

*Controller*

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/note")
    public class NoteController {

        @Autowired
        private NoteRepository noteRepository;

        @GetMapping(value="/debug")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Note>> getNotes(){
             return new ResponseEntity<List<Note>>(noteRepository.findAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
```